# Adding delay to promises

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

so I have a loop for creating promise when I do a request to a certain Url:

```
for (let j = 1; j < nbRequest; j++)

{
 const currentPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(
      `someUrl${j}`,
      (error, response, body) => {
        if(error || !response) {
          console.log("Error: " + error);
        }

    console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode + ", Connected to the page");

    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    let output = {
      ranks: [],
      names: [],
      numbers: [],
    };

   //some stuff to do

    console.log("HERE 1");
    return resolve(output);
  }
);
  });
  promises.push(currentPromise);
}
```

After that I'm writing result of my promises in a csv file :

```
Promise.all(promises).then((outputs) => {
  console.log('Request received');
  let ranks;
  let names;
  let numbers;

  outputs.forEach((output) => {
    ranks = _.concat(ranks, output.ranks);
    names = _.concat(names, output.names);
    numbers = _.concat(numbers, output.numbers);
  });

  for (i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++)
  {
    writer.write({Rang: ranks[i], Nom: names[i] , Nombre: numbers[i]});
  }
});
```

But here's the problem: I'm willing to add a delay between each promise.
Any idea ?

Comment: would something like this help 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/delay-promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially use the loop index to schedule each of the tasks inside the promises for a future time. For example your top section of code would look like this.

```
for (let j = 1; j < nbRequest; j++) {
  const currentPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      request(
        `someUrl${j}`,
        (error, response, body) => {
          if (error || !response) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
          }
          console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode + ", Connected to the page");

          var $ = cheerio.load(body);
          let output = {
            ranks: [],
            names: [],
            numbers: [],
          };

          //some stuff to do

          console.log("HERE 1");
          return resolve(output);
        })
    }, 1000 * j);
  });
  promises.push(currentPromise);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want delays between those functions then you shouldn't use `Promise.all` in the first place.

When you use `async` and `await` plus Bluebird for some nice addons, then you'll be able to use elegant things like this:

```
const { delay } = require('bluebird');
```

and in an async function:

```
doSomething();
await delay(100);
doSomethingElse();
await delay(3000);

// ...
```

Any time where you need complex time-dependent logic you should really use `async`/`await` if you don't want your code to get too complex.

For more info, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

For support in Node, see:

- http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions

In places where you don't have native support for `async` and `await` you can use Babel:

- https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/

or with a slightly different syntax a generator based approach like in `co` or Bluebird coroutines:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/co
- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html